# How to convert facebook profile picture to sprite in andengine?

Tags: android, facebook, andengine

When I start game then log in to Facebook post about game after that my profile picture is set on corner of game play.I did search on it but found mostly in android application that show our profile picture. But I cannot find any way to convert image return from  Facebook to texture region turns to sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can do as follows:

```
File imageFile = new File(image);
IBitmapTextureAtlasSource fileTextureSource = FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(imageFile);
ITextureRegion textureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(mBitmapTextureAtlas, fileTextureSource, 0, 0);
```

TRY THIS

Comment: But i am confused about that which path i can use for File class. Because assets/gfx cant use.

Comment: You will get Url path of facebook profile picture.Place that one.

Answer (score 0):

First get the bitmap of that profile picture.Then convert that bitmap to .png format using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769806/convert-bitmap-to-file) link.Then place that file name in Texture region.It will work

Answer (score 0):

check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341672/getting-the-real-facebook-profile-picture-url-from-graph-api) for getting url for facebook picture