# Android picasso, error reason

Tags: android, picasso, image-loading

How do I get error description in picasso :

```
    Picasso.with(context)
        .load(getUrl())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.user_thumbnail_big)
        .error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .into(viewModel.userImg);
```

Callback `onError`(https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/index.html) method also doesn't provide any arguments, I'm getting error images, but can't figureout why, logcat is also silent. Internet permission added.

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**

issue : [Picasso library stopped working today with facebook graph picture links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674680/picasso-library-stopped-working-today-with-facebook-graph-picture-links)

Comment: did you set viewModel.userImg?
check if getUrl() dont return "" or null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem I solved it through :

> The [global instance listener](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.Listener.html) receives HTTP exceptions for reporting upstream to a crash reporting service or analytics service.

regards to : https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/379

```
public class MyClass implements Picasso.Listener {
    @Override
    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
    // Display the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: so add  it where is the problem :P

Comment: You should add how to set the Listener on Picasso

Comment: My images didn't get loaded, but this Listener implemented in the same class did not get called. Using v2.5.2 with the problematic `.fit().centerCrop()`