# Picasso Images Will Not Load - Android / Java

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview, picasso

I'm attempting to use Picasso to load an ImageView from a URL - however the imageView never seems to populate with the image and I am unsure why.

P.S.

When debugging - the value of 'boxart' is a valid image URL each and every time - so I'm pretty stumped.

### Source:

...

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String boxart = extras.getString("boxart");
        Picasso.with(this).load(boxart).into(imageItem);
```

### ...

Also - I'm not getting any errors - it simply does not load the image.

Comment: Are you able to access the image url from within the browser?  It could be that you missing Internet access permissions on your manifest xml

Comment: Start from adding error listener to picasso

Answer (score 0):

Try installing an error handler and see if that gets called (you set this global listener on your [`Picasso.Builder`](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.Builder.html#listener-com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.Listener-):

```
public class MyClass implements Picasso.Listener {
    @Override
    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
        // Display the exception
    }
}
```

Full answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27798536/1715829

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

ex.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alefba.app.cus.eLearning"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also, make sure your device is connected to a network.

- be sure the link is direct