# Picasso not loading a particular image url

Tags: android, android-image, picasso

I am trying to load this `http://assets.myntassets.com/v1/images/style/properties/Jockey-Men-Black-Innerwear-Vest-9926-0105_435418e1b17c4d0c5583dd33ba24193d_images.jpg` url using picasso. On checking the logs it's showing `errored`. But when I tried the same url by:

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
Bitmap d = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

The image is loading. It is very strange. Could not figure why it is happening though.

Here is the logcat:

```
D/Picasso (27123): Main        created      [R9] Request{http://assets.myntassets.com/v1/images/style/properties/Jockey-Men-Black-Innerwear-Vest-9926-0105_435418e1b17c4d0c5583dd33ba24193d_images.jpg resize(720,1184) centerInside}
D/Picasso (27123): Dispatcher  enqueued     [R9]+7ms 
D/Picasso (27123): Main        created      [R10] Request{http://assets.myntassets.com/v1/images/style/properties/Jockey-Men-Black-Innerwear-Vest-9926-0105_435418e1b17c4d0c5583dd33ba24193d_images.jpg resize(720,1184) centerInside}
D/Picasso (27123): Hunter      executing    [R9]+15ms 
D/Picasso (27123): Hunter      removed      [R9]+21ms from 
D/Picasso (27123): Dispatcher  canceled     [R9]+21ms 
D/Picasso (27123): Dispatcher  enqueued     [R10]+16ms 
D/Picasso (27123): Hunter      executing    [R10]+16ms 
D/Picasso (27123): Dispatcher  retrying     [R10]+538ms 
D/Picasso (27123): Hunter      executing    [R10]+542ms 
D/Picasso (27123): Dispatcher  retrying     [R10]+1057ms 
D/Picasso (27123): Hunter      executing    [R10]+1062ms 
D/Picasso (27123): Dispatcher  batched      [R10]+1586ms for error (will replay)
```

Code for picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .resize(height,width)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(imgView);
```

Where `height` and `width` for this particular case is `720` and `1184` respectively.

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: @FaroukTouzi: Added the code.

Comment: You can try to load into a `Target` instead of directly into the `ImageView`. This way you can easily debug what is going on.

https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html

Comment: try removing `-` from url simply use `_`

Comment: also to check error try binding listener to picasso

Comment: I found a way to get more data on the error. maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798391/android-picasso-error-reason/

Comment: @KaranMer: I am afraid `onError()` of `ImageLoadedCallBack` does not have any parameter for why Image Failed to load.

Comment: you can use Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(Profile.this)
             .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                  System.out.println("Ex"+exception.toString());
                 }
             })
             .build();
    
    picasso.load(profilephoto)
    .transform(new CircleTransform())
    .into(img);

Comment: Okay Here is the issue: `https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/364`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/364) is the link to this issue reported on github.

Answer (score 0):

Following this example you will get a image that fits inside MAX_WIDTH and MAX_HEIGHT bounds (keeping aspect ratio)

```
private static final int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;
private static final int MAX_HEIGHT = 768;

int size = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(MAX_WIDTH * MAX_HEIGHT));

// Loads given image
Picasso.with(imageView.getContext())
   .load(imagePath)
   .transform(new BitmapTransform(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT))
   .skipMemoryCache()
   .resize(size, size)
   .centerInside()
   .into(imageView);
```

And this is my custom BitmapTransform class:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;
```

/**
 * Transformate the loaded image to avoid OutOfMemoryException
 */

```
public class BitmapTransform implements Transformation {

    int maxWidth;
    int maxHeight;

    public BitmapTransform(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
        this.maxHeight = maxHeight;
    }

 @Override
 public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    int targetWidth, targetHeight;
    double aspectRatio;

    if (source.getWidth() > source.getHeight()) {
        targetWidth = maxWidth;
        aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double)     source.getWidth();
        targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
    } else {
        targetHeight = maxHeight;
        aspectRatio = (double) source.getWidth() / (double)   source.getHeight();
        targetWidth = (int) (targetHeight * aspectRatio);
    }

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth,  targetHeight, false);
    if (result != source) {
        source.recycle();
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public String key() {
    return maxWidth + "x" + maxHeight;
}

};
```