# NoClassDefFoundError for OkHttpClient

Tags: android, facebook, classnotfoundexception

After adding the facebook dependency in gradle I'm getting this runtime error:

```
     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
```

Please notice that I'm also using okhttp:

```
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

and error log is:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-109754
     Process: com.venkat.project, PID: 4453
            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util
            at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:57)
            at com.venkat.project.http.MyHTTPThread.run(MyHTTPThread.java:127)
            at com.venkat.project.http.MyHTTPThread.run(MyHTTPThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-23 18:11:02.729 4453-4573/com.venkat.project I/dalvikvm: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient; v=0x0
```

Note: I'm getting this error on Samsung mobile 4.4 but on the emulator and on `moto g 5.0` it works.

Comment: `Clean and Build` your project

Comment: @MD no use. getting same error.

Comment: Try to open the apk and undex the classes. Check if the Util class was included in dexing.

As a temporary workaround, you could copy the class from sources and include it in your code. That way it will be in your classpath. (Here I stress the work "workaround" and "temporary)"

Comment: @Radovan if i remove the facebook dependency in gradle the app is woking ... but just if i add it give the error

Comment: @Venu Facing same problem yet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You are getting**

```
       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util
        at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:57)
        at com.venkat.project.http.MyHTTPThread.run(MyHTTPThread.java:127)
        at com.venkat.project.http.MyHTTPThread.run(MyHTTPThread.java:61)
```

### NoClassDefFoundError for OkHttpClient

```
public class NoClassDefFoundError extends LinkageError
```

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.

Quote from **[NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)**

You should use

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
```

After that you can get this error ***finished with non-zero exit value 2***

**Then**

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
    targetSdkVersion //Yours

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
 implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

1. Add  **[multiDexEnabled true](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)**
2. Call  `implementation'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'`

> OkHttp perseveres when the network is troublesome: it will silently
>   recover from common connection problems. If your service has multiple
>   IP addresses OkHttp will attempt alternate addresses if the first
>   connect fails. This is necessary for IPv4+IPv6 and for services hosted
>   in redundant data centers.

You can call latest version

```
implementation'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
```

**Then**

**`Clean and Re-Build & Sync`** Your Project . Hope this helps .

Answer (score 15):

The latest version of Piccasso use an older version of Okhttp, you need to use a new dependency

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'    
compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
```

Example:

```
File httpCacheDirectory = new File(getCacheDir(), "picasso-cache");
Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, 10 * 1024 * 1024);

OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(cache);
Picasso.Builder picassoBuilder = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext());
picassoBuilder.downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(clientBuilder.build()));
Picasso picasso = picassoBuilder.build();
try {
   Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
} catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {
  Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Picasso instance already used");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

**Multidex support for Android 5.0 and higher**

> Android 5.0 and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively
>   supports loading multiple dex files from application APK files. ART
>   performs pre-compilation at application install time which scans for
>   classes(..N).dex files and compiles them into a single .oat file for
>   execution by the Android device. For more information on the Android
>   5.0 runtime, see Introducing ART. That means your app would working fine on API level 21 or above.

**Multidex support prior to Android 5.0**

> Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 use the Dalvik runtime
>   for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single
>   classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this
>   limitation, you can use the multidex support library, which becomes
>   part of the primary DEX file of your app and then manages access to
>   the additional DEX files and the code they contain.

Try adding this

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Alternative to that, If your app extends the Application class, you can override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
    MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
    super.onCreate(arguments);
    ...
}
```

Finally, you will need to update your build.gradle file as below by adding multiDexEnabled true :

```
defaultConfig {  
        applicationId '{Project Name}'  
        minSdkVersion 15  
        targetSdkVersion 23  
        versionCode 1  
        versionName "1.0"  
        multiDexEnabled true  
    }
```

I hope it will help you out.

Comment: Attribute “name” was already specified for element “activity”

Comment: @marco I didn't get your point? and why did you down vote please enlighten me . What mistake did I made.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have enabled proguard.
If you do not need proguard in your application then you can disable it in your build.gradle(app)

```
debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

And if you need proguard in your application then follow this [link](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2230) where Mr. Jake Wharton have solved this.