# Retrofit 2 with Google play service exception

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2, retrofit2

I get very weird problem. I was using retrofit 2 for my http request. It works fine but when I add compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'` dependency and runs my application it gives exceptions like below.

```
07-09 11:10:59.769 7425-7425/com.example.plugshare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.example.plugshare.MainActivity.getOpenChargingStation(MainActivity.java:27)
 at com.example.plugshare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:359)
 at com.example.plugshare.ServiceGenerator.<clinit>(ServiceGenerator.java:35)
 at com.example.plugshare.MainActivity.getOpenChargingStation(MainActivity.java:27) 
 at com.example.plugshare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.internal.Util
 at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:61)
 at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:359) 
 at com.example.plugshare.ServiceGenerator.<clinit>(ServiceGenerator.java:35) 
 at com.example.plugshare.MainActivity.getOpenChargingStation(MainActivity.java:27) 
 at com.example.plugshare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.plugshare"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
// retrofit, gson
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'}
```

I am not able to find solution for it. Anyone one know please help me to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @Shashanth did you find anything wrong?

Comment: This question might helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578135/noclassdeffounderror-for-okhttpclient