# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class okhttp3.OkHttpClient

Tags: jar, okhttp, noclassdeffounderror, splunk

As part of solving GIT vulnerability issue, i upgraded splunk-library-javalogging from 1.7.0 to 1.11.1.

But when i deployed this to my k8s cluster i am getting error like
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class okhttp3.OkHttpClient

I changed my deployment version to previous one, then it works fine. Not sure why changing version to 1.11.1 gives me this error

This is working

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is not working

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And i have to upgrade to 1.11.1 or higher to resolve GIT vulnerability issue. I have read many solutions but i did not find any answer helpful. This is a maven project and i am running it on java 8.

Also, running jar file in my local doesn't give the error. Issue is only in k8s cluster

Update 4th Mar 2022
i explicitly declared  version after reading some solution on the internet like below

```
<mockwebserver.version>4.7.2</mockwebserver.version>
<okhttp3.version>4.7.2</okhttp3.version>
```

But now i am getting slighly different error
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication|Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'okHttpClientBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/commons/httpclient/HttpClientConfiguration$OkHttpClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder]: Factory method 'okHttpClientBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class okhttp3.internal.Util

Earlier error was
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication|Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'okHttpClientBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/commons/httpclient/HttpClientConfiguration$OkHttpClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder]: Factory method 'okHttpClientBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class okhttp3.OkHttpClient

Comment: Do you understand what a NoClassDefFoundError is?

Comment: Yes, Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html

Comment: You don’t bring in the library with that class in anymore.  Your transient dependencies have most likely changed.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand at all. I am at beginner level. Can you please tell me exactly what caused the issue and what is the solution? Thank you for taking your time to reply

Comment: i checked effective pom in eclipse <okhttp3.version>3.14.9</okhttp3.version> This is the version for okhttp3

Comment: Is the jar present in what is deployed to kubernetes?

Comment: I really don't know how to check jars in k8s or docker repo. i checked but couldn't find this details. i have update my question. can you please check and suggest

Answer (score 2):

A jar cannot file express which other jars it depends on in a way that the jvm will understand,the runtime will not detect unfulfilled dependencies until it needs to access them. this will lead to a noclassdeffounderror crashing the running application, well known as [Jar-Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) problem, there are many maven goals (such as `mvn dependency:analyze` )and plugins can help you to have dependency analyze, or on language level you can adopt modular programing to prevent this kind of exception but generally using `<optional>` or `<exclusion>` tags on direct dependencies that request the transitive dependency is the most available choice to have version and [duplicate](https://guides.dataverse.org/en/latest/developers/dependencies.html#id6) dependency control .

Comment: See more in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35692941/15758781

Comment: @Luntic , i have update the question , can you please check after "update" and suggest

Comment: Dear @Lucky for improving the community please don't update the question when the answer receives , pease consider to accept my first suggested as answer and approve it as answer, indeed i will attach an other answer for updated question .

Comment: Sorry, but I really did not get your answer. I tried running mvn dependency:analyse to find out used but undeclared dependency but i could not find http3 in that list. I am really new to this IT industry. Please help me out .