# Does facebook delete original version of uploaded image after a while?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

From by web application, I have been uploading different ratio image on my Facebook page for last 30 days by Graph-API. After posting it on my page I grab the original image link and show it on my application. I check the dimension of the uploaded image after each upload process and get the original one from it. But today suddenly I noticed that the link of those original images are not loading. For example I am getting the below for this [link](https://scontent.fdac59-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/119065117_136705784682077_8618659457450093142_o.png?_nc_cat=110&_nc_sid=2d5d41&_nc_eui2=AeETj2cQ_go5XjDG7O3DE8Ry_rbxkGkOWwH-tvGQaQ5bAavNu-hmFEYD4-FRw9PsFxS0jV0lh_oxKfsz9rUWPtXZ&_nc_ohc=T2s9YEibPzMAX-mPk4M&_nc_ht=scontent.fdac59-1.fna&oh=f29de8fd9387eac8e69cb0e7b2ce4e25&oe=5F7DDDB5)

[image]

Although the image is still showing on my Facebook page. So my question is, does Facebook remove the original image link after a while? If not why the link is not available? What should I do now to make it workable again. Thanks a lot in advance.

Very few among them are still loading. Like this [link](https://scontent.fdac27-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/118392293_130570015295654_7404968679829769554_o.png?_nc_cat=108&_nc_sid=2d5d41&_nc_ohc=vWYhoO0PF6AAX-VgAy4&_nc_ht=scontent.fdac27-1.fna&oh=252b4d85f43ab2e586745ea4e433e073&oe=5F69F273) is still working.

**PS: It's not about the code, and my code is working fine, but to make you understand I also share the code with you**

```
function postImageOnFacebookPageAndGetPhotoID(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    FB.api(
      '/'+pageID+'/photos',
      'POST',
      {"url":url, "access_token":document.getElementById("pageAccessToken").value},
      function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
          reject(response.error);
        } else {
          resolve(response.id);
        }
      }
    );
  });
}

function getOriginalUploadedImageURL(photoID, imageWidth, imageHeight) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    FB.api(
      '/'+photoID,
      'GET',
      {"fields":"images"},
      function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
          reject(response.error);
        } else {
          var imageArray = response.images;
          imageArray.forEach((item) => {
            // console.log("item.width "+item.width+" item.height"+item.height);
            // console.log("item.source "+item.source);
            if (item.width == imageWidth && item.height == imageHeight) {
              resolve([item.source, item.width, item.height]);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    );
  });
}

function deleteFacebookPageImageByPhotoID(photoID) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    FB.api(
      '/'+photoID,
      'DELETE',
      {},
      function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
          reject(response.error);
        } else {
          resolve("success");
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: The CDN URL is not valid forever. Use the API to get a valid CDN URL.

Comment: @WizKid Thanks for your comment. Can you please describe by code what do you mean? Instead of `FB.api()` what else should I use?

Comment: You should use FB.api. What does getOriginalUploadedImageURL return?

Comment: Those are all CDN URLs.

Comment: Yes. And they are valid for a time then they stop working. So every time you need a URL you should call that function.